# Title: Issue with using the "Request" class in Remix/Cloudflare Pages development environment

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cloudflare, remix.run

I'm currently working with Remix (react) , Miniflare and Cloudflare Pages, and I encountered an error while writing tests. The error message states: "ReferenceError: Request is not defined."

```
import { loader } from '~/routes/example'

test('loader test', async () => {
  const response = await loader({
    request: new Request('http://localhost:xxxx/entries'),
    params: {},
    context: {},
  })
  console.log(response)

  expect(response).toBeInstanceOf(Response)
})
```

```bash
FAIL  app/tests/core/example-01.spec.ts
  ✕ loader test (1 ms)

  ● loader test

    ReferenceError: Request is not defined

      3 | test('loader test', async () => {
      4 |   const response = await loader({
    > 5 |     request: new Request('http://localhost:xxxx/entries'),
        |                  ^
      6 |     params: {},
      7 |     context: {},
      8 |   })

      at Object.<anonymous> (app/tests/core/example-01.spec.ts:5:18)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.002 s
Ran all test suites matching /app\/tests\/core\/example-01.spec.ts/i.
```

In my code, I'm using the Request class without importing it because it doesn't show any errors in my IDE. However, when running the tests, the error occurs. I noticed that when I jumped to the definition of Request in my IDE, it led me to the following code in index.d.ts:

```
declare class Request extends Body {
  constructor(input: Request | string, init?: RequestInit | Request);
  // Other properties and methods...
}
```

Based on this, it seems like Request is not a module that needs to be imported but rather a native object provided in the browser or Node.js runtime. I'm using Miniflare as my development environment, and I assume it has its own implementation or polyfill for the Request class.

Despite the fact that my IDE recognizes the Request class without any issues, the error occurs during test execution, indicating that the test runner or environment cannot properly interpret the Request class.

Can someone explain why this error is happening and suggest a solution for using the Request class in my tests without encountering the error?

I tried importing the file where Request is defined, but it failed.

● Test suite failed to run

javascript
Copy code
Cannot find module '@cloudflare/workers-types/index' from 'app/tests/core/example-01.spec.ts'

1 | import { loader } from '~/routes/example'

> 2 | import '@cloudflare/workers-types/index'
> | ^
> 3 |
> 4 | test('loader test', async () => {
> 5 |   const response = await loader({

at Resolver._throwModNotFoundError (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:427:11)
at Object. (app/tests/core/example-01.spec.ts:2:1)

Comment: Have u tried importing it like this: `import { Request, Response } from "undici";`?

Comment: @DVN-Anakin Thank you for your response. I have made the necessary changes to the code, but I am still encountering a type error indicating that 'referrer' is missing. Even when I set a dummy referrer, it doesn't seem to work.
`TS2741: Property 'referrer' is missing in type 'import("/root-path/node_modules/undici/types/fetch").Request' but required in type 'Request'.`
Although the test now passes, I have noticed that it passes regardless of the URL I pass in the input, and I have confirmed that the corresponding loader function is not being executed.

Comment: PS: "the test now passes" means "no error was found in the relevant area during the test".

Comment: If the dummy `referrer` didn't work, then the `Request` class provided by `undici` is useless, you can uninstall it. 
I think You were on the right track when you tried importing the `Request` class from your code base. 
You have to somehow fix this error: `Cannot find module '@cloudflare/workers-types/index' from 'app/tests/core/example-01.spec.ts'`. 
Could you verify that the `@cloudflare/workers-types` package is installed in your `package.json` and if the path `@cloudflare/workers-types/index` matches the actual location of the package's entry file?

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I apologize for the delayed response. I have confirmed that the @cloudflare/workers-types package is installed and I found the index.d.ts file, which indicates that the package's location is correct.